# Which excel file called my C# dll?

Tags: c#, dll

I have an unmanaged C# DLL that is added to an Excel VBA code.

```
Private Declare Function DoSomething Lib "myc.dll" Alias "invokePath" (ByVal strRule As String)
```

Now from within the DLL, I need to know the path of the excel file that has made a request.

I need to then read the values from cells in the Excel workbook from within the C# DLL.

Comment: What's the question then? What did you try?

Comment: [`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx)

Comment: And... exactly why that path can't be a parameter?

Comment: There's no way to find out, either through COM or a stack trace.  Simply add whatever arguments you need to get the job done.

Comment: thanks. It was a genuine problem, which I was trying to resolve. I was hoping that DLL files can know which application name (in my case Excel file) had invoked them. This could have uses like logging, in my case to receive a pointer to the file. I did tried hard to look for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible I would implement this as a COM add-in, rather than importing the function from VBA. In this way you will have access to the Excel `Application` instance which will be the starting point for fetching data from the spreadsheet and interacting with Excel beyond simply returning a value from the function.

If you are calling this as a User Defined Function (UDF) then you will also be able to access the `Application.Caller` property, which will give you a reference of the cell that triggered evaluation of the UDF.